# Dynamically setting the href of a Facebook widget

Tags: dynamic, href, facebook-widgets

I have a little web app that uses the Facebook like widget.  This page also uses querrystrings to load content dynamically.  I need the href assigned to the Facebook widget to be determined dynamically based on the querrystring.  Here is an example of how I define the widget:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=186609524720286&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like id="fbLike" href="http://apps.facebook.com/inflatableicons/image_preview.html" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like>
```

But what I really need is something like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=186609524720286&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like id="fbLike" href="http://apps.facebook.com/inflatableicons/image_preview.html?y=119" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like>
```

Notice that href in the second example ends with with ?y=119 but the first one does not.  My problem is that I will not know which value to put as the querrystring for the widget till I see which querrystring is passed to the html page.  Can anyone explain how I could insert a dynamic value into the href?  I first tried to do set the href after the fact like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=186609524720286&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like id="fbLike" href="#" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like>
<script>
  var url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/inflatableicons/image_preview.html?y=120';
  document.getElementById('fbLike').setAttribute('href', url);
  console.log(document.getElementById('fbLike'));
</script>
```

but when I do this the widget complains that href is not set, strangely when I print the value of getElementById it shows the href that I set with setAttrbibute, even though the widget does not think it was set correctly and gives an error.  I believe that for some reason the widget will not allow me to set the href after the fact.

**EDIT:**

I also tried using the jQuery example that ferni descried in his answer but this did not seem to work:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=186609524720286&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like id="fbLike" href="#" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like> 
<script>
    var url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/inflatableicons/image_preview.html?y=120';
    jQuery("#fblikeblock").html('<fb:like id="fbLike" href="'+url+'" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>');
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikeblock'));
    console.log(document.getElementById('fblikeblock'));
  </script>
```

I added the console.log to the end of the script to print the value of fblikeblock and that returned null so this may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add the **fb:like** button to the page and then call the XFBML processor on it. So something like this (I'm assuming jQuery is the library in use: you'll have to change it if you're using something else):

```
var url = "http://apps.facebook.com/inflatableicons/image_preview.html?y=119";
jQuery("#fblikeblock").html('<fb:like id="fbLike" href="'+url+'" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>');
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikeblock'));
```

EDIT: a potential implementation of this solution would be this.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=186609524720286&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<div id="fblikeblock"></div>
<script>
    var url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/inflatableicons/image_preview.html?y=120';
    jQuery("#fblikeblock").html('<fb:like id="fbLike" href="'+url+'" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>');
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fblikeblock'));
    console.log(document.getElementById('fblikeblock'));
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to use your jquerry script but the button still complains that there is no href when I use the code I posted in my last edit.